# Why does the innerHTML of several inline-blocks nested in a block element affect the positioning of the inline-blocks?

Tags: css

In these examples (NOTE: make sure you drag out the result window wide enough)

http://jsfiddle.net/pPyaG/

http://jsfiddle.net/pPyaG/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/pPyaG/2/

Why does the quantity of text inside the inline-block elements affect the positioning of the inline-blocks in the same div?

What can I do to make sure all the inline-blocks nested inside the block element have the same vertical alignment with respect to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` where you have `display: inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pPyaG/3/

The initial value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`, which causes the issue you're experiencing.

Read this, particularly the "baseline" section: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

A comparison of how common values of `vertical-align` look: http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html