# Chrome rendering odd CSS layout (Firefox and IE are good)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout, page-layout

This is what my HTML page looks like in Firefox and IE: 
[image: Page layout in Firefox and IE]

And this is the same page in Google Chrome:
[image: Page layout in Google Chrome]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="header">
    <div id="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Manage</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar"></div>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="articles-overflow"> 
      <div id="articles-strip">

        <div class="article-month-column">
          <div class="article">
            <div>
              <h1>Article 1.1</h1>
              <p>
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="article">
            <div>
              <h1>Article 1.2</h1>
              <p>
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="article-month-column">
          <div class="article">
            <div>
              <h1>Article 2</h1>
              <p>
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
                This is some idiotic text.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="article-month-column"></div>
        <div class="article-month-column"></div>
        <div class="article-month-column"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>

</div>
```

And here is the CSS for the red, yellow, violet, white and green containers.

```
#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

#content {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

#articles-overflow {
  margin: 10px 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
}

#articles-strip {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.article-month-column {
  width: 224px;
  height: 450px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background: darkviolet;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}

.article {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

p {
  padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 1em 0px;
  font-size: 7.5pt;
  text-align: justify;
  background: green;
}
```

Please, is there any way to fix this? I have been struggling with this for day now and I simply cannot understand why Google Chrome renders the page layout in such strange way. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the innerHTML of several inline-blocks nested in a block element affect the positioning of the inline-blocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404529/why-does-the-innerhtml-of-several-inline-blocks-nested-in-a-block-element-affect)

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top` where you have `display: inline-block`.

Comment: just add float:left to .article class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the `vertical-align` for those `inline-block` elements.

Also, there's a little bit of extra CSS you should have when using inline-block for older versions of IE.

> ```
> .article-month-column {
>   width: 224px;
>   height: 450px;
>   margin-right: 15px;
>   background: darkviolet;
>   display: inline-block;
>   overflow: auto;
>   white-space: normal;
>   vertical-align:top;
>
>   /*For IE*/
>   *display: inline;
>   zoom:1;
> }
> ```