# Why does the inline-block element appear below the inline element? How to make them appear on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to understand basic HTML and CSS concepts and came across a very peculiar problem. I have two elements one having display: inline and the other having display: inline-block. I am trying to create a list, something of this sort `1. SOME CONTENT THAT WILL OCCUPY MORE THAN ONE LINE` I have the numeral as an inline element and the corresponding content as an inline-block. I don't want to use `<ul>` or `<ol>` as it involves fairly esoteric CSS that I am not prepared given the place where I am at.

My question is if the content of the inline block element is more than one line then why does the inline-block element appear on a line of its own? From what I understand the width of inline and inline block elements are constrained by the content.

I tried setting vertical-align: top but to no avail. I looked at this question on stack overflow: [Why does the innerHTML of several inline-blocks nested in a block element affect the positioning of the inline-blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404529/why-does-the-innerhtml-of-several-inline-blocks-nested-in-a-block-element-affect).

```css
#numeral{
display: inline;
}

#content {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"     charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
    <span id="numeral">1.</span>
    <span id="content">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH      BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH                                   BLAH</span>

  </body>
</html>
```

I expected the next line to start directly below the inline-block element but this is not happening. How should I achieve this effect?

Comment: Please use the code editor by clicking the brackets icon `<>` (7th icon from the left) and pasting your code there (refer to  [mcve])

Comment: @zer00ne Done. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block`* will not share a space inline with another element if you don't give it a width. So either `inline` both which is sloppy, or use `inline-block`, `widths`, and `vertical-align` for smaller content such as `#numeral`. Note, `#numeral` width is `2ch` a ch unit is roughly about the width of a character for the exact description see this [article](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/#article-header-id-11)

*<sub>when it's content exceeds the width of it's element's parent's width</sub>

### Demo

```css
#numeral {
  display: inline-block;
  width:2ch;
  vertical-align:top
}

#content {
  display: inline-block;
  width:90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="numeral">1.</span>
  <span id="content">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH      BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH </span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

An inline-block element is placed as an inline element (i.e. on the same line as adjacent content) **Only if it's width will fit within the remaining space.**

In order to understand this better, specify the width of #content so it will fit next to #numeral (**display: inline-block allows to set a width and height on the element**) as following:

```
#numeral {
    display: inline;
}

#content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: That solved it! Can you explain why this works in more detail? Thanks a ton!

Comment: An inline-block element is placed as an inline element (i.e. on the same line as adjacent content) Only if it's width will fit within the remaining space. So in your case, the width of #content was wider than the available space that is next to #numeral because the default width of inline-block is to shrink-to-fit its content which is wider than the available space.

Comment: Had similar issue, vertical-align: top; solved it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to reduce the length of the 'blah' text you will find that your markup does what you desire.  But that doesn't solve the problem in its totality for removing the `display: inline-block` css property from the `#content` id selector will achieve a similar result. Again the question is why?

The answer lies in the very central question you asked: *if the content of the inline block element is more than one line then why does the inline-block element appear on a line of its own?* You should strive to answer and understand this query as it will lead to a satisfactory answer.

The answer is to better understand three vital elements of HTML5 and CSS3 that you cannot avoid if you wish to wield web development tools to your needs: [normal flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Block_and_Inline_Layout_in_Normal_Flow) of a document, the [css box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model) including the [visual formatting model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model) and the [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).

a great free resource that will give you ample exposure to these fundamentals, in addition to the resources I've already provided at the MDN, can be found at freecodecamp.org under their responsive web design course. They are quick and insightful. The [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/) also provides a great resource for study and examples.

Grasping these root concepts will give you the arsenal you need to tackle these problems and I have provided them in the order of study.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly the second span is using a closing tag of `</div>` make it `</span>`

Not sure what you're going for if it's a numerated/bulleted structure but you can make both of the spans display `inline`:

```
#content, #numeral {
 display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Hi Cesar, I have corrected that. What I am trying to achieve is something of this sort `1 . Some content that will expand over multiple lines.` To achieve this I am using two elements, one inline and the other inline-block. The numbered list should have the numeral and the content where the content is aligned. Thanks!