# How to make an inline-element appear on the same line within a column?

Tags: javascript, less

I have a question very similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172579/why-does-the-inline-block-element-appear-below-the-inline-element-how-to-make-t). The main difference is that I'm trying to place this block of text within a column. Here is my code

```
<div class="row" className="list">
   <div class="column">
      <div>
         <span className="number">1. </span>
         <span className="words">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <div>
         <span className="number">2. </span>
         <span className="words">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <div>
         <span className="number">3. </span>
         <span className="words">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   width: 100%;
}
.column {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-basis: 100%;
   flex: 1;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 1em 2em;
   .number {
      display: inline-block;
   }
   .words {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 1em;
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 90%;
   }
}
```

However, the `BLAH BLAH` text appears on a newline on my Mac screen, but is aligned at the top of the number on a bigger monitor. Is there a way to wrap the text "tighter" (i.e. allow fewer words per line) so that the entire text block is indented *and* appears on the same line as the number?

Comment: Clarification needed:  Your CSS isn't valid - are you using SASS instead? Your HTML also has invalid elements - is this part of an app?

Comment: The `className` attribute is not a valid attribute for HTML/CSS (did you take an example from a `React` code?), even if Chrome still seems to interpret it, but maybe on the MAC/Safari it doesn't recognize it. Replace `className` attributes with the standard `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  .number {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .words {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1em;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row" className="list">
  <div class="column">
    <span className="number">1. </span>
    <span className="words">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span className="number">2. </span>
    <span className="words">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span className="number">3. </span>
    <span className="words">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This gave me the same problem. On my Mac screen, the entire block of text is on the line below my number.